# Is it possible to find unclosed JSX tags in React Native with ESLint?

Tags: react-native, eslint, jsx

For example, the below code block doesn't fail elegantly using ESLint with `eslint-plugin-react` and `eslint-plugin-react-native`:

```js
const challengeButton = user.button !== this.state.button ?
  (
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.handleChallenge(user.username)}>
      <View>
        <Text>Challenge</Text>
      </View>
      {/* missing </TouchableHighlight> */}
  ) : (
    <View />
  );
```

This fails with an Unexpected Token many lines after the fact. Is there a way to catch the missing end tag for the `TouchableHighlight`?

Comment: My eslint catches it right away. Can you post your package.json + .eslintrc ?

Answer (score 0):

**The airbnb config catches unclosed JSX tags**

I like to use the airbnb eslint config. It is very opinionated and may be more than your asking for. [Check it out](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript) and if you like it I made a one liner you can use to easily add it to your project.

**Just run it from the root of your project**

`npm install --save-dev eslint-config-airbnb babel-eslint eslint-plugin-react eslint && echo '\''{ extends: [airbnb], }'\'' > .eslintrc`